# adding logic in PHP for printing

Tags: html, css

I am just starting with PHP and having trouble of getting my page result to print right. I call the page below from index.php. It looks ok if I displayed the page on a monitor but when I print the page and it is more than one page, the section at the end of the page got cut off and continue on the second page. I am looking for a way so that when I print the page, it will look if the section (each item number) will fit the whole section (repair desc, common cause, etc) in that page. If it does not then just print on the next page.

I also included the CSS file. Basically what it does is forcing the width of page to fit a letter-size paper. Thank you in advance.

```
 <?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .
    '/fms/includes/helpers.inc.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Print Repair Form</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/fms/css/letter-size.css' />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page-wrap">
    <table>
    <tr>
          <td rowspan = "3" id="logo"><a href="/fms/"><img src="/fms/images/flex_no_address_256.jpg" /></a></td>
      <td rowspan = "3" id="address">Address<br />
        City, State Zipcode <br />
        Phone number <br />
        website address
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
              <td id="repairinfo" class="theading" colspan = "2">Repair Detail</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><?php htmlout($custno); ?></td>
          <td width="100px">WO: <?php htmlout($wonum); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><?php htmlout($custname); ?></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
     </table>
     <br />
     <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
     <table border ="1">
    <tr>
      <td class="theading">Type of Repair</td>
          <td class="theading">Repair ID</td>
      <td class="theading">Fault Picture</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tablepadding"><?php htmlout($item['repairtype']); ?></td>
      <td class="tablepadding"><?php htmlout($item['itemno']); ?></td>
      <td rowspan="7" align="center">
          <img src="/fms/images/wo_items/<?php htmlout($item['filename']); ?>"          width="256" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="theading" colspan="2">Repair Description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tablepadding" colspan="2"><?php htmlout($item['repairdesc']); ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="theading" colspan="2">Common Causes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tablepadding" colspan="2"><?php htmlout($item['commoncause']); ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="theading" colspan="2">Preventive Measures and Maintenance</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tablepadding" colspan="2"><?php htmlout($item['maintenance']); ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
      </table>
      <br />
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {
    font: 12px/1.4 Georgia, serif;
}

a img {
  border: none;
}
#page-wrap {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
    width:100%;
}

#logo {
    width: 256px;
}

#address {
    width: 170px;
}

#repairinfo {
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
}

.theading {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px;
}

table tr td.tablepadding {
  padding: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be achieved through CSS and no PHP, although you can use php as well as a workaround, google for css media.

There are some tricks for the CSS of your printing: http://slodive.com/web-development/css-print-page-tricks/

Can't give you specific details because I haven't worked too much with printings but it all comes to testing the total height that fits on the paper, and looking for a measure in php (maybe lines?) so if the size is bigger than the one you set, it creates another Table.

You could also use Javascript as you can detect element's (for example a table's) height, and call some function when the max height is reached.

---

Also I want to suggest you not using tables if it's not totally necesary, It's a very old-school approach and troublesome to modify, with more different behaviour across browsers, and with a lot more of unnecesary code.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not with PHP but with CSS. 
You need to include a print specific stylesheet as this will be different to your computer monitor styles.

Here's a good blog post about print CSS
http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml

In your html the print stylesheet `<link>` element will need a `media="print"` attribute

Then in your print stylesheet you can specify a width